# Checking uncommon fields in Excel

Tags: excel

So I had a test at school where I could not solve this question, I wanted to know how it can be solved. It goes something like :

You have been given two Excel spreadsheets, one has 200 records while the other has 300. Devise a formula/method to figure out which 100 records are not present in the first file.

Could anyone tell me how this can be solved?
I could use COUNT to calculate that there are 100 records, but I need the values of the records. Is there anyway to use COUNTIF to solve this, or is there some other way?

We are allowed to import it into Access too if it cant be solved in Excel.

Edit : Example below -

Lets say the first spreadsheet has the records Q, W, E and the second spreadsheet has the records Q, W, E, R, T, Y. I need a function which returns the values : R, T, Y (as they are the values not present in the first spreadsheet)

Comment: If there are columns with common values, you can use vlookup on the longer list; for the non-common fields, vlookup will return an error.  the match function could be used as well.

Comment: Lets say the first spreadsheet has the records Q, W, E and the second spreadsheet has the records Q, W, E, R, T, Y.

I need a function which returns the values : R, T, Y (as they are the values not present in the first spreadsheet)

Comment: loop through the longer list and look up each value in shorter list if not there  then add to a Collection.

Comment: @user2140261 How exactly would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

open both files and in the bigger file, add a column with formula using some lookup function, e.g. **[MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx)**:

```
=ISNUMBER(
   MATCH(cell_from_this_row,
         range_of_all_such_cells_from_smaller_table,
         0))
```

filter all "FALSE" values to get the missing rows

Comment: Match function is my go-to for de-duping or identifying values not present between two tables/sheets/etc.  +1

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Could you please tell me what ISNUMBER does? I have never used it before.

Comment: +1 Interesting formula, and I've learned another formula today! @FlameDra: You can remove the `ISNUMBER` part to see what happens if you don't have it :)

Comment: @FlameDra see **[IS functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx)** - `ISNUMBER` will return TRUE if value is a number, FALSE otherwise (in this case for `#N/A`) - feel free to use inside `IF()`

Comment: @FlameDra yes, you just need to filter `#N/A` instead of `FALSE` (2 clicks and a lot of scrolling instead of 1 click + it won't work inside an IF() function)

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example, you can put the formula for `VLOOKUP` in the longer spreadsheet (let's say the longer spreadsheet is `Sheet2` and the shorter one `Sheet1`).

In an additional column of `Sheet2` of the first record:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)
```

Drag and fill down for the records of Sheet2 and all the ones you don't have in `Sheet1` will return `#N/A`. You can then filter on these `#N/A` to get the records not found in `Sheet1`.

What `VLOOKUP` does is that is looks for the value in `A1` into the column `A` of `Sheet1` and returns the value that matches in the column index `1`. `FALSE` means it looks for an exact match.

Note that `VLOOKUP` is case insensitive.

---

You can still do it with `COUNTIF`.

This time, the formula is:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A, A1)
```

The formula is a little simpler and shorter to execute if you have a lot of records. It will return `0` in case it cannot find the value it's looking for in the other sheet.

Comment: @FlameDra Are you putting the `COUNTIF` in `Sheet2`?

Comment: Yes, but I guess since VLOOKUP is working it should be enough.

Comment: @FlameDra: Strange... what is happening with the `COUNTIF`?

Comment: + 1 For the simple way of doing it.